# Docker (docker-compose.yml file) Define the Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

This is pertaining to Docker and docker-compose file:
I saw this in an answer a while ago and I need some clarification from the below code .

```
networks:
  cfsext:
    driver: macvlan
    **ipam:** <- What is this for?
    config:
      - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipam` is an object where you can define your config under it like `ip_Address`, `gateway`, `ip_address range`

**https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipam

Comment: @nexusguy59: Hope this answered your question. ?

Comment: @nexusguy59: Please accept the answer as you got desired information